Stackelberg Game with three players
My friend and I were solving the following game for assignment, and came up with different solutions. Could any one help us know whose solution is right?
Suppose there are 3 firms in a homogeneous good market, which set their quantities sequentially (firm $i$ in period $i$). Suppose firms have zero marginal cost of production.The industry faces an inverse demand $P(q) = 16-q$ where $q=\sum_{i=1}^3q_i$ is the aggregate quantity. Solve for $q_1$.
Both agreed to the following:(See Rigorous solution of Stackelberg leader-follower game with N-players?)
$$q_i = \frac{1}{2}(16-\sum_{j=1}^{i-1}q_j)$$
$$q_i = \frac{1}{2}q_{i-1}$$
My Solution:
$$max_{q_1}Pq_1=max(16-q_1-\frac{1}{2}q_1-(\frac{1}{2})^2q_1)q_1 $$
$$=(16-\frac{7}{4}q_1)q_1$$
Applying the FOC results in $q_1=32/7$ with the profit level $\frac{32\cdot8}{7}$.
Her Solution:
Applying i=1 to the first equation provides $q_1=8$. Hence, the profit level is $(16-(8+4+2))\times 8 = 16$.
Could anyone tell us which solution is right?

Firm 3 will choose $q_3$ after observing $q_1$ and $q_2$ in the following way. It solves the following problem:
\begin{eqnarray*}\max_{q_3\geq 0} & \ (16-q_1-q_2-q_3)q_3\end{eqnarray*}
and we get
$q_3=\dfrac{16-q_1-q_2}{2}$
Firm 2 will anticipate firm 3's response as above and choose $q_2$ after observing $q_1$ in the following way. It solves the following problem:
\begin{eqnarray*}\max_{q_2\geq 0} & \ (16-q_1-q_2-q_3)q_2 \\ \text{s.t.} & q_3=\dfrac{16-q_1-q_2}{2}\end{eqnarray*}
which can be re-written as
\begin{eqnarray*}\max_{q_2\geq 0} & \ \frac{(16-q_1-q_2)q_2}{2} \end{eqnarray*}
and we get
$q_2=\dfrac{16-q_1}{2}$.
Firm 1 will anticipate firm 2 and 3 to respond in the manner above and choose $q_1$ by solving
\begin{eqnarray*}\max_{q_1\geq 0} & \ (16-q_1-q_2-q_3)q_1  \\ \text{s.t.} & q_3=\dfrac{16-q_1-q_2}{2} \\ \text{and} &  q_2=\dfrac{16-q_1}{2}\end{eqnarray*}
which can be re-written as
\begin{eqnarray*}\max_{q_1\geq 0} & \ \frac{(16-q_1)q_1}{4} \end{eqnarray*}
and we get $q_1=8$.
